# Quebec City Passenger Lists ... 1865-1900: Devising a scheme to view the first page of a passenger list

Tags: 19th-century, manifest, canada, quebec, norway

I am writing about a *Library and Archives Canada* collection, "[Quebec City Passenger Lists Index 1865-1900](http://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/databases/passengers-quebec-1865-1900/001082-130-e.html)." This is a collection of indexed names and digital images said developed from RG 76, the official Canadian immigration documents.

I've been able to locate the passenger list line entries for my ancestors. (Very exciting.) I also want to be able to view the pages that precede and follow that on which my ancestors are recorded.

I'd have preferred to browse all the pages of this particular list, but most certainly  want to view the first and last pages of the list. (The first page and last pages often have information about the ship/voyage that isn't repeated on the other pages).

After much tinkering, the best I have been able to do is poke at random indexed entries and save the different named image files that return.

After *quite of bit of poking*, **I've manage to save eight sequentially numbered image files** (e003533634.jpg through and including e003533641.jpg). For all my poking, I have still not saved an image that I would assume to be the first page of the list.

Likewise, I haven't made enough sense out of the image URLs to manually browse the different pages either.

I'm hoping the diverse expertise here on Genealogy.SE might have a solution for me. Some details follow.

Search page: [Quebec City Passenger Lists Index 1865-1900](http://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/databases/passengers-quebec-1865-1900/001082-100.01-e.php)

Search parameters:

- Ship Name: Atalanta
- Arrival Date: 23 Jun 1871 (Quebec)

The clip below shows how I searched and found the relevant index.

[image]

Any suggestions or workarounds for how I might browse these images is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you've found almost all the pages.  There is a summary on http://data2.collectionscanada.gc.ca/e/e142/e003533633.jpg which is the first page, then there's the sequence from 34 onwards that you've already found.

Each ship starts with a summary page (which often looks like the last page).

So as a general technique (for others), when you've found a page about a journey, you can right click on the image that you get from a search and select open in new tab, then modify the numbers in the URL by 1 to step forwards/back.

Comment: Wow. You certainly broke the URL code. (You'll understand if I don't admit to the poking and devising time I invested in vain. TYTY, Rob. I've not yet found the manifest header (top part of what I might consider the first page of the list), but I'll use this approach to persevere.

Comment: I doubt there is anything else.  http://data2.collectionscanada.gc.ca/e/e142/e003533642.jpg for example is the first page of the next ship, and even untidier (see the scrawled 41 on it, your ship is 42, count is descending).  The pages before your ship were from Bergen (and have 43 on some of them).  So I think that final page (image 33) is the lot.

Answer (score 2):

The following is from http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread736264/pg1

[QUOTE]
The disclosed Canadian UFO files can be found on the website of the “Library and Archives Canada” (a Canadian government website) at the link below:
www.collectionscanada.gc.ca...

That website includes documents from the Department of Transport, Department of National Defence, the Royal Canadian Mounted Police and the National Research Council.
**The “Library and Archives Canada” website includes a helpful search page and you can browse the collection by leaving all the fields blank and simply pressing “search”. Using that method, you can click on each of the records, but this is a fairly slow process (although nowhere near as slow and painful as browsing the Footnote.com website’s collection of American UFO documents on a bad day – see the thread entitled Massive UFO disclosure in USA : A challenge for ATS.)**

Unfortunately, the official Canadian website does not offer an option for downloading the entire collection of UFO documents.

However, each individual document can be accessed using URLs such as the one below (ending “/e/e110/e002744278.jpg”):
data2.collectionscanada.gc.ca...

The images have URLs with blocks of consecutive numbering (e.g. URLs ending /e/e110/e002744278.jpg, /e/e110/e002744279.jpg, /e/e110/e002744280.jpg etc etc).

[END QUOTE]

Comment: Thank you. Though you guys have cracked the case (so I'm just following the links that are posted), I still don't get them myself when I view the image. Here's the link that comes up for me on the image otherwise e003533639.jpg: http://www.collectionscanada.gc.ca/databases/passengers-quebec-1865-1900/001082-119.03-e.php?&interval=50&person_id_nbr=198711&&PHPSESSID=78epdrajprtlesene58rqremq6

Comment: GeneJ, I'm using Firefox and once the image is onscreen I right click the image and then select "View Image Info" from the displayed menu items- Mac may be different.

Comment: I needed to right click the image again to open it in a new window; that brought up the data2 URL. Thanks, @AndyHatchett. That was part of my missing action.